# What UI element is used in Google Analytics Custom reports?

Tags: gui-design, terminology, google-analytics

Both the metric group and drilldown dimensions in the Google Analytics Custom report use an interesting user interface (UI) element where the user can add any amount of elements to a list. These are effectively button menus themselves. Both the add button and already added elements have the same menu behaviour.

What would you call a list like this?

[image: Google Analytics Custom report]
[image: Metric group selection menu]

Answer (score 1):

I tried searching for a considerable amount of time but could not find the particular widget/element used in the Google Analytics Custom Report screenshot you have attached.

This seems to be a custom widget itself consisting of a Web version of the Android widget: [**ExpandableListView**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) but it does not contain the expansion for the sub-element.

The sub-element expansion is provided for a newer component. This one is known as [**Expansion-Panels**](https://material.google.com/components/expansion-panels.html) in the updated doc for Material Design.

It is a list, with dropdowns inside to reveal more hidden information.

Could not find the exact terminology for you, but I hope this should help you with any research.

Comment: Hadn't thought to check the Developer documentation this time. Really appreciate the idea. However, these examples seem to be more similar to concertinas (accordions). The list is really the key here. Similar to how Google lays out Triggers in Google Tag Manager.